# Why do groupBy in Haskell need two variables to check

Tags: haskell

I was going through groupBy in Haskell and the way I understand it is that the groupBy function takes a List and a condition and groups the element based on the specified condition.

```
let value = [-3,-5,-1,1,1,1,2,3,-1,-2]
groupBy (\x y -> (x > 0) == (y > 0)) value
```

It works fine, but why should we give two variables in the lambda function? Why does "groupBy (>0) value" not work? Also should both the conditions be the same? What will happen if they are different. Please explain with examples.

Comment: ``groupBy ((==) `on` (>0)) value`` should also work, after you import `Data.Function` for the `on` helper.

Comment: If you don't want the property of `groupBy` that it groups *adjacent* objects, it sounds like you want `partition`.

Answer (score 5):

[Lignum's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42329748/2751851) explains why the `groupBy` predicate takes two arguments. To put it in another way, `groupBy` sets up boundaries, and you need two sides to be able to define a boundary.

> Also should both the conditions be the same? What will happen if they are different.

Yes, they should. As the [`Data.List` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#g:24) notes...

> The predicate is assumed to define an equivalence.

In other words, if `p :: a -> a -> Bool` is the predicate you pass to `groupBy`, then all of...

- `p x x = True`
- `p x y = p y x`
- if `p x y && p y z` then `p x z`

... should hold. Weird things happen if that isn't the case. For instance, we might at first think that...

```
groupBy (\x y -> (x > 0) == (y < 0)) [-1,2,-3,-4,2,1,2,-3,1,1,2]
```

... would produce groups composed of alternating above zero and below zero elements. Instead, we get bogus results:

```
GHCi> groupBy (\x y -> (x > 0) == (y < 0)) [-1,2,-3,-4,2,1,2,-3,1,1,2]
[[-1,2],[-3],[-4,2,1,2],[-3,1,1,2]]
```

(The reason it goes wrong is that the guarantee of the predicate being an equivalence is exploited by implementing `groupBy` in terms of `span`.)

---

Finally, there is a nicer way of writing your `groupBy` predicate: using [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) from `Data.Function`:

```
GHCi> groupBy ((==) `on` (> 0)) value
[[-3,-5,-1],[1,1,1,2,3],[-1,-2]]
```

`` (g `on` f) x y = g (f x) (f y) ``. You might even define:

```
-- A more general type: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBySingle :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBySingle p = groupBy ((==) `on` p)
```

Answer (score 2):

> [...] the way I understand it is that the groupBy function takes a List and a condition and groups the element based on the specified condition.

Not entirely, it groups *adjacent* elements based on the specified condition. Notice how your code evaluates to this list:

```
[[-3,-5,-1],[1,1,1,2,3],[-1,-2]]
```

instead of this list:

```
[[-3,-5,-1,-1,-2],[1,1,1,2,3]]
```

Therefore, the lambda expression that you pass to `groupBy` determines whether two *adjacent* elements should be in a group together.

Answer (score 2):

`groupBy` operates by checking whether the current element belongs to the group based on the previous one.

The behaviour you want is best descibed by a separate function, repeatedly applying `span` and `break`:

```
myFunc :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
myFunc _ [] = []
myFunc p xs = satp : notsatp : myFunc p rest
  where
    (satp, rest') = span p xs
    (notsatp, rest) = break p rest'
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say "is best described by [...]" -- the OP's implementation is fine; it's just that it is slightly unusual to see `(==)` on `Bool` being used as a biconditional.

Comment: Actually, there is one thing immediately related to the OP's question that counts in favour of your approach: `groupBy` expects an equivalence predicate, so we aren't at all supposed to pass things like `(\x y -> (x > 0) == (y < 0))` to it.